# Using WebClient in a controller tested with @WebFluxTests throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not absolute

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-test

I have a `@RestController` that uses `WebClient` in one of its endpoints to invoke another endpoint from the same controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class FooRestController {

    private final WebClient webClient;

    @Value("${service.base-url}")
    private String fooServiceBaseUrl;

    @GetMapping(value = "/v1/foo", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public Flux<Foo> getFoo() {
        return webClient.get().uri(fooServiceBaseUrl + "/api/v1/fooAnother")
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToFlux(Foo.class);
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/v1/fooAnother", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public Flux<Foo> getFooAnother() {
        return Flux.xxx
    }
```

In my `@WebFluxTests` class I can test the `fooAnother` endpoint without any problem:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@Import({MyWebClientAutoConfiguration.class})
@WebFluxTest(FooRestController.class)
class FooRestControllerTest {

    @Test
    void shouldGetFooAnother() {
        xxx
        webTestClient.get()
                .uri("/api/v1/fooAnother")
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus().isOk()
    }

    @Test
    void shouldGetFoo() {
        xxx
        webTestClient.get()
                .uri("/api/v1/fooAnother")
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus().isOk()
    }
```

However when I test the `/v1/foo` endpoint (notice in my tests `service.base-url`=""), it fails calling `webClient.get().uri(fooServiceBaseUrl + "/api/v1/fooAnother")` having `fooServiceBaseUrl + "/api/v1/fooAnother"` = `"/api/v1/fooAnother"`, complaining that it need an absolute URL: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not absolute: /api/v1/fooAnother`.

How could I fix this test?

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure your `WebClient` using `WebClient.Builder()`. You could do this inside your `FooRestController` but I like to use `Configuration` that way if you have any further WebClient customizations, you could do in different class rather than in your controller class.

Configure WebClient:

```
@Configuration
public class WebClientConfig() {

    @Value("${service.base-url}")
    private String fooServiceBaseUrl;


    @Bean
    public WebClient webClient(WebClient.Builder builder) {
        return builder
            .baseUrl(fooServiceBaseUrl)
            .build();
    }
}
```

If you decide to go ahead with configuring your webClient in your `FooRestController`, you have to refactor as below. You don't need above configuration.

If this doesn't solve your issue, you might have some sort of mismatch between `application.yml` file and the value that your are trying to inject in `fooServiceBaseUrl`.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class FooRestController() {
    private final WebClient webClient;

    @Value("${service.base-url}")
    private String fooServiceBaseUrl;

    public FooRestController(WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder) {
        this.webClient = webClientBuilder
                .baseUrl(fooServiceBaseUrl)
                .build();   
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/v1/foo", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public Flux<Foo> getFoo() {
        return webClient
                .get()
                .uri("/api/v1/fooAnother")
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToFlux(Foo.class);
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/v1/fooAnother", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public Flux<Foo> getFooAnother() {
        return Flux.xxx
    }
}
```

Comment: As I said in those tests `service.base-url=""`, that value is set in an `application.yml` file. The problem here is that the RestController's WebClient isn't able to invoke a relative URL, unlike `WebTestClient`.